# Manipulating ergodic Markov chains in order to make them non-ergodic

Tags: probability, markov-chains, ergodic-theory, markov-process

Consider a Markov chain, for simplicity let us consider time discrete chains.

## The problem

We consider a TDMC (Time Discrete Markov Chain) $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ with $X \in \mathcal{X}$ (having $\mathcal{X}$ as the set of the chain states) under the assumption that the chain is **ergodic**.

Without going deeper into the reason that make me ask such a strange question, I would like to make the chain non-ergodic.

## The question

Is there a way to make an ergodic chain non-ergodic?

For example by adding states preserving the old ones?

What approaches in literature, does anybody know?

### In particular

I would like to preserve the environment of the network, I mean that given certain initial states, the chain should have a limit behavior that is coherent. If for example I use an absorption state, as I was suggested in one answer, should I use one absorption state connected to all states or an absorption state for every node?

Thankyou

Comment: Crosspost: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26729/manipulating-ergodic-markov-chains-in-order-to-make-them-non-ergodic

Comment: I voted for closing the one in stat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible: just add one "absorbing state" with even a single incoming edge of nonzero probability, but no outgoing edges.  Then, the chain is no longer ergodic because the original states are no longer positive recurrent.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, please see my edit

Comment: @andry: I edited in response.  Even a single edge is enough.  If the original chain was ergodic, entering the absorbing state is inevitable.